# Powershell filtering does not recognize variable

Tags: powershell, filter, window

Hi i have below code to assign group to user

```
$User1 = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the username of the employee you wish to change'
    $CountryList = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Country ISO - PL, CZ, HU, SE, 

RO'
    $CountryList = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Country ISO - USA, CZ, HU, SE, RO'
    Disable-AdAccount -Identity  $User1
    Set-aduser $User1 -clear manager
    Get-ADUser -Identity $User1 -Properties MemberOf | ForEach-Object {
    $_.MemberOf | Remove-ADGroupMember -Members $_.DistinguishedName -Confirm:$false |

    $Group_Name = Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like "*#GG-$CountryList-O365-EXCHANGE"}
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group_Name -Members $User1
}
```

The problem is that filter does not recognize variable $CountryList

How can i solve this ?

Comment: You are not checking any of the values a user might type in with `Read-Host`. What if someone enters 'USA, CZ, HU, SE, RO' or 'The Netherlands'? `Get-ADGroup` returns a collection of groups that match the filter. You should loop over these groups.  Also, it is not clear what your groups are named like. Can you give an example?

Comment: for example #GG-USA-O365-EXCHANGE, #GG-CZ-O365-EXCHANGE ect ?

Comment: the issue is with this part  $Group_Name = Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like "*#GG-$CountryList-O365-EXCHANGE"} where filter can not recognize the value from $CountryList, don't know why , it should be there country iso

Comment: @WiktorKostrzewski use a string filter instead: `-Filter "Name -like '*#GG-$CountryList-O365-EXCHANGE'"`

Answer (score 1):

I would use another variable here that you pass into `$Group_Name`:

```
$CountryList = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Country ISO - USA, CZ, HU, SE, RO'
$Filter = '*#GG-'+$CountryList+"-O365-EXCHANGE"

$Group_Name = Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like $Filter}
```